# Cannot upgrade node and hence not able to install npm AND @angular/cli on ubuntu16.04LTS

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, angular-cli, npm-install

Nodejs is installed already, and it can be concluded by nodejs --version output.
[image: npm install issue]

Also, please note when I tried to upgrade node, I was getting the below error while doing apt-get update:

```
sudo apt-get update
.
..
Err:13 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Sources                                                        
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
Ign:17 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages                                                 
Ign:20 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages                                                  
Ign:22 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages                                                   
Ign:23 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US                                              
Ign:24 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en                                                 
Ign:25 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata                                          
Ign:26 http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons                                             
Fetched 204 kB in 12s (16.5 kB/s)                                                                                 
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.152 80]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Not sure what the issue is, however guessing some name conflict as I read somewhere ubuntu also has some package named 'node', however need to get through this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Node 4.x is end of life. Try [updating](https://nodejs.org) to a newer version. You would likely never get Angular to install properly with the old version.

Comment: Not sure why someone just downvoted the question!
It is a genuine problem I'm facing and all the details are mentioned .
It will be great if the downvoter also put some comment specifying his/her reasoning behind downvoting the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surprisingly, Ubuntu 16.04 was the only culprit here.

If you visit the ubuntu package [here](http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/), it looks like xenial package is not present.
I fixed this by commenting this in sources.list.

So the fix here is:

1. Open file /etc/apt/sources.list.
2. Comment all the lines which have
   this url: http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu .

As these packages are not
    actual ubuntu source, we shouldn't have any impact by commenting it out.

**PS:** Also created one gist [here](https://gist.github.com/manish-tiwari/a3339330550296e1400190203a050079) for tracking this issue with ubuntu 16.04LTS.